# How to add shop items automatically

Tags: prestashop, items

I'm newbie, when it comes to prestashop, so here is my question:
I have to add a few thousands of products to my shop (prestashop), how may I automate it? 
They will differ only in picture/name. Presta doesn't allow me to add multiple items at once, and doing it manually is a nightmare. Maybe a script? But... where do I put and how to execute it?
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for menu Avanced Parameters -> CSV Import. There you can find examples of how to massive upload products to your shops and wich field you must use and wich one are required.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe a script?

Definetely maybe!

But what script language do you know enough to automate process youself?

Ok, lets imagint that PHP is almost your native language :)

In such case this docs would help you enough

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Developer+tips+and+tricks#Developertipsandtricks-HowtoimportproductsfromaXMLfile

... yes, I know the documentation is poor, very out of date, ugly and uncomplete, but it was starting point for me to build my supplier Excel-prices impor/update tool. So I hope it will help you to survive in this wild PrestaWorld :)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost - thank you guys for quick answers! I'll probably stick with CSV.

@AlexandrX

I 'speak' python and PHP. Actually I could write that script in one of mentioned, but i wasn't sure how to "put them inside" presta. As I said, I'm really new to that topics. But will try. Thanks ;)